# Assigning a different (new) JPanel to a JTabbedPane at run time

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbedPane (say myTabPane) having one tab (lets take only one tab for clarity sake). While creating the JTabbedPane, I added a JPanel (say panel_A) to this tab. I have a button on this JPanel. The tab displays my JPanel perfectly with the button on it. So far so good.

I have defined a listener on the button which creates an instance (say panel_B) of another class extending JPanel. This JPanel has got a different set of components on it. I want panel_B to super-impose panel_A. That is, JTabbedPane's tab should show panel_B and hide panel_A. 
Please note that I am able to display panel_A OR panel_B when I "bind" the respective panel (one of them) to the tab during creation of the JTabbedPane. However, I want a selective display (or binding, whichever is possible) of only one of the panels with a button-click (ie. at runtime). 
How can this be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
myTabPane.removeTabAt(0);
myTabPane.addTab("B", panelB);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Simple and effective solution. However, this approach would work only when there is one tab in the tabbedPane. My bad that I mentioned about one tab. However when there are multiple tabs, this would shift all the tabs one place to the left and add my originally First tab at the last with panelB showing. The shifting of tabs is what doesn't go well here. Any idea how to circumvent this?

Comment: Alright, I got this working now :-)
All I needed was to remove the tab from the index, and then **insert** a tab at the desired index, and then set the selected index containing my new JPanel. Thanks Dan for your pointers :)